# Laravel - pass filter to a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, filter

I need some help here. Essentially, there are two tables (tblplayers & tblmatches). Not every player exists in tblmatches.  My controller has this code:

```
use App\Model\Players;
use App\Model\Matches;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PlayersController extends Controller
{
public function index(Request $request) {
$players = Players::select('*');
```

I would like to change my select statement above so that it only returns players that also exist in tblmatches (where tblmatches.P1_ID = tblplayers.ID).

What am I doing wrong below?

```
$players = Players::addSelect(DB::raw('(SELECT * from tblmatches where (P1_ID = ID))'));
```

Should I be changing the model instead? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add *one to many* relation (details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)) to your player model (and probably also to your Matches model)

```
public function matches()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Matches');
}
```

And [query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) it by

```
$players = Players::has('matches')->get();
```

Comment: Nice!  Thank you sir.  Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely set up a [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) between the two tables. It would make cases like this, so much easier to handle.

However, what you are looking for is essentially a `WHERE EXISTS` instead. So, something like the following should do the trick.

```
$players = Players::whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('tblmatches')
            ->whereRaw('tblmatches.player_id = tblplayers.id');
    })
    ->get();
```

I made an assumption that you have those two fields in the `whereRaw()`, but you should change it accordingly.

```
whereRaw('tblmatches.player_id = tblplayers.id');
```

However, definitely take a look at relationships :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution threw an error "BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addSelect does not exist."

Comment: Based on the error message, it feels like you are chaining `addSelect()` to the result (which is a Collection). You should not do that. `$players` itself will contain a Collection of `Players` model you can work with. It should work :)

Comment: Here's a working [example](https://implode.io/HS4OqL) you can play with, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

```
 protected $table = 'tblplayers';
   public function fetchPlayers ($data) {
    $players =  DB::table($this->table)
   // you can filter it by Boolean expression using where 
    ->where('status', '<>', 1)
   // you can group by
    ->groupBy('status')
    ->get();
    return $players;
  }
```